# It's possible to get the inverse dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have strange question =). Maven has beautiful command - mvn dependency:tree, which shows dependency modules in tree, for example module A depends on module B.
Maybe mvn has some plugin which shows  where used module B? For example- module B used in A

Answer (score 1):

Such a question can't really be answered by a plugin, because it would only know about modules within the current reactor build. There could be some other dependency somewhere else - but dependency information is only ever stored in one direction.

Having said that, you can use the `--also-make-dependents` switch when building a multi-module project, and it will build the dependent modules of the module you specify. Thus, you can see what they are.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such mechanism in maven.

For the maven central repository, the search engine http://mvnrepository.com/ provides a section *This artifact is used by ...*

Answer (score 1):

You may use dependency:tree with variable "includes":

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=groupId:B
```

It will give something like

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building B 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ B ---
[INFO] groupId:B:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building A 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ A ---
[INFO] groupId:A:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- groupId:B:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building C 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ C ---
[INFO]
```

Then you see that only modules A and B have dependency trees which includes module B.

Answer (score 0):

The [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) might help, at least when looking at a large multi-module structure.